# How to get started using flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best Open Source tools for developing Flash applications? What are the best places to start learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153468/what-are-the-best-open-source-tools-for-developing-flash-applications-what-are-t)

Hi, I would like to start learning a bit about flash. What editors would I need? right now I am a web developer using asp.net mvc, c# and visual studio 2010. Is there a free flash editor or can I use visual studio? Anything to get started?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488808/how-should-a-programmer-go-about-getting-started-with-flash-flex-actionscript

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there's a great IDE called Flashdevelop. Its actually better than the Flash IDE for actionscript. It uses the free Flex compiler (or Flash IDE compiler) but can target Flash or Flex Apps.
You may need the Flash IDE to create some resources, but you can do alot with just Flashdevelop
if you code your objects.

http://www.flashdevelop.org

Answer (score 1):

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is an excellent option. Free, small, fast, and simply awesome.

There also VS plugins. Check out this similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967108/is-there-an-actionscript-extension-for-visual-studio).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

As you are a developer so i suggest to go to adobe site and download Adobe Flash Builder (60 days trial) that will be easy to work with for you. Using that you will be able to create web and mobile applications. for animations you can use Tweener classes if you are going to flash for animations. When you have installed flash builder then you will see tutorial link at splash screen.